# Calculate integral with infinite?

Tags: integration

I have done some integration in the past, but came across the following question:

[image]

The question is simple, calculate the integral and give the final answer. I am really not sure what to do and how I fill in the infinite values. Could somebody give me some more insight in how to solve this question.

Comment: 1. What is $\delta(t)$? 2. Your title suggests something with $(x-1)$, your question does not have any $x$ at all.

Comment: Kind of my question too, I don't know. Changed the title sorry, I am kind of braking my hand on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When integrating agains the delta function the result is evaluation at the origin. Thus $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t)f(t)dt = f(0)$ more generally $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-x)f(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t) f(t+x) dt = f(x)$$

Comment: Should that last part  not be f(t)*-x? Maybe you could put a little more information about the last equation. I am not really getting that part

Comment: The Delta function is 0 for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ except for $x = 0$. At this point it is infinetly high. If you integrate over it multiplied with $f$, you get the value of $f$ at $0$. By subtracting $-x$ in the argument, you can move the delta function to match $f(x)$ instead of $f(0)$.